# How to check whether or not a particular cell value is modified in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am a beginner in Google Sheets. I want to know how I can detect a cell value is changed.

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have two columns in the Sheets, one is the 'Modified Date', one is 'Value', i.e,

```
Modified Date              Value
---------------------------------
09/21/14                     5
```

I want the date to be automatically updated ONLY if the value of the second column is Changed. For example, if I change '5' to '10' on Jan 1st 2015, then the date will be changed automatically to 01/01/15.

I was trying to create a custom function isModified() and assign a function like "=IF(isModified(B1), today(),)"  to the first column, where isModified ideally should return true if the given cell's value is modified, false otherwise. Is there any built-in function or custom function in add-ons store that does like isModified()? If not, how can I create my own function that detects the modification of a cell's value?

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All  you have to do is to implement the simple trigger `onEdit(event)`. Following a possible solution:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;

  if (range.getColumn() == 2){
    var previous = range.offset(0, -1,1,1);
    previous.setValue(Date());
  }
}
```

On the proposed solution, the hole date and time is written in the cell "Modified Date". I did this way to make sure the script is working fine. In the case you want just the date, you can change `Date()` by `new Date()`.

Hope it is useful! If not, let me know:)